# How to update Picture in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 1 picture in Fragment2 in my APP (Tabbed Activity) and i need to change (update) that picture every day. But, i want to do it realtime and without people having to update the app every single time from Google Play Store.

I'm a beginner and I am using Java language, how to do it?

This is my code:

```
package com.example.probica;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.Storage;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.probica.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Contact mail: ofbbettingtips@gmail.com", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, create a ref to a path that contains a imagem file.

```
private val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
private photoRef = storageRef.child("FolderName").child("photo name")
```

With "photoRef" you'll have you photo reference. You'll need to decode it with BitmapFactory. Than use as you want.

Open the firebase storage console and upload the image on correct path, you should be able to see it in your app.

Upload the image on correct location whenever you want, users will see it without update the app itself from playstore.

You can use firebase realtime DB or Cloudfire storage

Comment: How do I decode my photo reference with BitmapFactory (what even is photo reference)? 

I'm a complete beginner so i'm sorry for dumb questions

Comment: Reference is like the path. A file in your PC may be located at Home/Documents/MyDocs/MyPhoto.jpg Thats the file path.

Firebase works like that, but we navigate through the folder based on references. 
You can think in something like home.child("Documents").child("MyDocs")...

Take a look here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Here you'll get some ideas on references and how to upload the file as a Byte Array

Comment: Hey Filipe, i'd like to ask you some questions about my app via mail, if that's okay with you, send me your mail, thanks in advance